# How to create list workflow with two approvers?

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I'm interested on how to make a request vacation workflow which has two approvers associated with the request.

- the logic I need is when any of the two approvers approve the request workflow goes on

I don't want to wait other approver to complete his task because they have the same role when it comes to vacation requests.

- of course when any of approvers approve or reject the request, I want Approval task to be deleted or something similar for approver who didn't click on Approve Request task

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Create a workflow with SharePoint Designer. 
2 - Add a Paralel Block
3 - In paralel Block add two identical Approval Process with different Approvers